# How to skip the "-- More --" in PostgreSQL pager?

Tags: windows, postgresql

When PostgreSQL spits a long output (eg. `SELECT * FROM table_name` for a table with 1000 lines), it will only show the first 50 or so lines.

There's a "-- More --" line at the bottom.

If you press enter, it will show the next line.

How can I skip the long PostgreSQL's output?

This is a PostgreSQL 12 run on cmd on Windows 10.
I tried:

- `\q` on the --more-- line, then enter: just show the next line
- `\pset pager off` is my current solution, although no ideal for showing table with 1000 row

```sql
dbname=# SELECT * FROM table_name;
  id  |   first_name   |     last_name     |                 email                 | gender | date_of_birth |         country_of_birth
------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------+--------+---------------+----------------------------------
    1 | Erroll         | Craisford         | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-05-28    | Indonesia
    2 | Son            | Smitherman        | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-02-16    | Indonesia
    3 | Dion           | Primo             | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2018-12-14    | Thailand
    4 | Florette       | Waldock           |                                       | Female | 2019-05-23    | Palestinian Territory
    5 | Roderick       | Stowte            | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-01-24    | Poland
    6 | Hi             | Kleeman           | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-01-26    | Indonesia
    7 | Ethelind       | Gard              | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2018-11-05    | France
    8 | Bartel         | Melhuish          |                                       | Male   | 2019-02-18    | Vietnam
    9 | Smith          | Gavahan           | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-05-04    | Sweden
   10 | Harmonia       | Defrain           | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2018-12-17    | France
   11 | Eulalie        | Cuerdale          | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-05-09    | Angola
   12 | Floria         | Bernette          | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-07-07    | China
   13 | Ruddy          | Scargle           | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-08-27    | Norway
   14 | Vinson         | Capewell          | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-01-24    | Portugal
   15 | Eben           | Yellep            | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-03-12    | Mexico
   16 | Yolande        | Blaasch           | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-01-22    | Philippines
   17 | Tiphani        | Whitlow           | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-01-01    | New Zealand
   18 | Alvina         | Carne             | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-03-01    | Peru
   19 | Peg            | Hains             | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-02-22    | Indonesia
   20 | Arlana         | Sibson            | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Female | 2019-06-15    | Niger
   21 | Rabi           | Slimme            | xxx@yyy.zzz                           | Male   | 2019-03-03    | Belarus
   22 | Marianna       | Gouthier          |                                       | Female | 2019-05-06    | Sweden
-- More  --
```

Comment: Hoping these is just dummy data and no real dataset. If just: Immediately remove them!

Comment: Maybe something like `PAGER='head -25' psql`?

Comment: @S-Man it's a dummy data from mockaroo.com, I was doing a postgresql tutorial video. 
The answer (solved) is press `q`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just press `q`.

For more options see man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html#COMMANDS

Comment: This is the answer, thank you! I did not expect this to be this fast!

Comment: The man page had my answer: use Space for more, not Enter